# Bash, sed doesn't overwrite with semicolons

Tags: bash, sed

hy, i have to write a script that take the output of ps and rewrite it in a csv file; the problem is that i have to delimiter every camp with ";" but sed doesn't want to accept it, i try with:

```
ps --no-headers -o "%u : %U : %p : %a" | sed -e 's/\:/";"/' > file.csv
```

but it doesn't work becouse it overwrite : with "" and not with ;
there's everybody could help me?

edit:
i have another problem: i need the camp user, pid, command, start time and cpu time, but i have to write it in a csv file with every camp divided by ; so the problem is that the pc where i have to run it doesn't accept the %T for start time so i have no idea how to do this script

Comment: `:` is not a meta-character in `regex`. There is no need to escape it.

Comment: What prevents you using `;` inside the format string? `ps --no-headers -o "%u ; %U ; %p ; %a"`? There is no need to `sed` any more.

Comment: excluding the process `ps --no-headers` itself from the output should solve your problem - no need to use sed here I think

Comment: Also, please avoid combining two questions in one when possible, the narrower the question spread the better the answers will be.

Answer (score 2):

This ps command doesn't seem to run on my Mac but if the problem is with sed, taking `;` out of it's quotes should fix it.
`sed -e 's/\:/;/'`

However, this will only replace the first `:`

So I think
`sed -e 's/\:/;/g'` is what you need

Comment: nope, i have to save it to a csv file but it dowsn't work, in the csv the : is overwrite by a backslash

Comment: @ValentinoScevaScevaroli I can not reproduce this issue. Tested on Ubuntu 16.04